# Can't open image files with Picasa in Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: 12.04, wine, image-viewers, picasa

I have installed Picasa using Wine but I am not able to open any image using it as Picasa does not appear in the list of applications which can be changed to default program for opening image files.

Answer (score 1):

Open Picasa and go to

**Tools > Options > File type**

Check the boxes next to all the file types and click <kbd>OK</kbd>

[image: Tools-options-file type]

Answer (score 1):

Create a desktop entry for Picasa like this:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Version = 1.0
Icon ="path to your favorite icon"             
Type = Application
Exec = "Path to your wine program e.g. wine "c:\picasa.exe"
```

Information on how to set the values for `.desktop` file can be found [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UnityLaunchersAndDesktopFiles).

and save it as `/usr/share/applications/picasa.desktop`

then you should be able to set it as your default image viewer.